# Missing nodes in solution (maze DFS solving algorithm)

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search, maze

I have a problem with my DFS algorithm missing nodes from solution (check image). It happens every time my algorithm encounters a dead end: the node is poped from stack to go back till available move is found, and is never reincluded again. Is there a easy way to fix it without reimplementing whole algorithm?

[image: Few missing nodes in solution are marked with red arrow]

```
    final int start = maze.getStart();
    final int stop = maze.getStop();
    final int columns = maze.getColumns();
    final int[] moves = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; //North, E, S, W
    int position = start;

    Maze.Cells cells = maze.getCells();
    cells.setVisited(position);
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    visitCells:
    while(position != stop){
        boolean[] availableMoves = cells.getAvailableMoves(position); //only visit yet unvisited cells
        for(int move : moves){
            if(availableMoves[move] && maze.isMovePossible(position, move)){
                position = doMove(position, move)
                cells.setVisited(position);
                stack.push(position);
                continue visitCells;
            }
        }
        position = stack.pop();
    }
    return stack;
```

I hope that the code is sefl-explicable. Drawing algorithm is correct, so I dont post it here. Don't hesitate to ask for more information in comments.

Comment: Would it be possible to refactor the while loop as a recursive method? Itll make your code cleaner and eliminate the need for that label. I doubt it will help your problem.

Comment: @BenKnoble I have to run it through really big instances so I would prefer to avoid use of recursion as it might cause unexpected stackoverflow :)

Comment: Makes sense. Sometimes there is a valid reason for labels (sometimes).

Comment: The DFS tag is MS's "distributed file system." I don't think that tag is relevant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you make a move from A to B, you are pushing the new position B onto the stack.  This means that when you backtrack you never get back to A.

Try reordering:

```
            position = doMove(position, move)
            cells.setVisited(position);
            stack.push(position);
```

to

```
            stack.push(position);
            position = doMove(position, move)
            cells.setVisited(position);
```